# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: transaction is not mapped

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-8

I have an error like this : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Transaction is not mapped [SELECT NEW model.DailyReport(SUM(c.amount), date(c.transactionTimestamp)) FROM transaction AS c GROUP BY date(c.transactionTimestamp)]`

and here is my code :

```
String queryStr = "SELECT NEW model.DailyReport(SUM(c.amount), date(c.transactionTimestamp)) FROM Transaction AS c GROUP BY date(c.transactionTimestamp)";
    TypedQuery<Transaction> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr, Transaction.class);
query.setFirstResult(offset);
    query.setMaxResults(limit);
    return query.getResultList();
```

Help me, BTW I'm new in JPA. Thx!

Edited :

Here is my Transaction Class :

```
@Table(name = "Transaction")
@Entity
public class Transaction implements Serializable{   
    @Id // ID
    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String srcAccountId;
    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String dstAccountId;
    private Double amount;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = Json.JSON_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date transactionTimestamp;

    // Setter and Getter here
   
}
```

And here is my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RestNeo-1" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/RestNeoDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the `Transaction` class?

Comment: Done, edited now.

Comment: The name of the table in your database is `Transaction` right? Or is it `transaction`?

Comment: It's Transaction btw

Comment: The `Transaction.class` parameter that you've passed to createQuery is your Transaction class right?

Comment: Yep, right bro..